# Get disk usage of a specific process in C#

Tags: c#, .net

How can I get the disk usage (MB/s) of a specific process in C#?

I am able to get CPU usage and RAM usage like this:

```
var cpu = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", ProcessName, true)
var ram = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set - Private", ProcessName, true);

Console.WriteLine($"CPU = {cpu.NextValue() / Environment.ProcessorCount} %");
Console.WriteLine($"RAM = {ram.NextValue() / 1024 / 1024} MB");
```

But I can't find anything related to the disk usage.

Like shown in the task manager:

[image: et]

Comment: See here for a list of per-process PerformanceCounters: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms804621.aspx One or more of those related to I/O might be of interest for you (depending on what exactly you need/want)

Comment: Seems like the closest counter is "IO Data Bytes/sec", but it sums up the traffic from network, devices and "file" (disk) I/Os. The other solutions I've found so far are too overkill. I'll stick with this one.

Answer (score 0):

## ♻️ Approach

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1640041/11465149)<sup><sub>[^2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948539/get-disk-utilized-by-each-process-in-c-windows)</sub></sup>:

> This API will tell you total number of I/O operations as well as total bytes.

> You can call GetProcessIoCounters to get overall disk I/O data per process - **you'll need to keep track of deltas and converting to time-based rate yourself.**

**So**, based on [this C# tutorial](https://programmingtutorial.net/csharp-programming/example/10061086/5-18-getprocessiocounters) you could do something along those lines:

```
struct IO_COUNTERS
{
    public ulong ReadOperationCount;
    public ulong WriteOperationCount;
    public ulong OtherOperationCount;
    public ulong ReadTransferCount;
    public ulong WriteTransferCount;
    public ulong OtherTransferCount;
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern bool GetProcessIoCounters(IntPtr ProcessHandle, out IO_COUNTERS IoCounters);

public static void Main()
{
    IO_COUNTERS counters;
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach(Process process In processes)
    {
        try {
            GetProcessIoCounters(process.Handle, out counters);
            console.WriteLine("\"" + process.ProcessName + " \"" + " process has read " + counters.ReadTransferCount.ToString("N0") + "bytes of data.");
        } catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception ex) {
        }
    }
    console.ReadKey();
}
```

<sup><sub>Use [this](https://converter.telerik.com/) to convert it to VB.NET</sub></sup>

#### But (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception ex) occurs

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
   at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.OpenProcess(Int32 processId, Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessHandle(Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.OpenProcessHandle(Int32 access)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_Handle()
   at taskviewerdisktest.Form1.Main() in C:\...\source\repos\taskviewerdisktest\taskviewerdisktest\Form1.vb:line 32
```

<sup><sub>Some processes seem to be really hard to access.. good news is that not many of them tho in my case (15 out of 250 or something) ..</sub></sup>

<sub>*⚠️ **Disclaimer:** this is more like an aproach towards "The solution" rather than "The solution"*</sub>

## ♻️ Other Approaches & References

- [GetProcessIoCounters function (winbase.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprocessiocounters)
- [IO_COUNTERS structure (winnt.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-io_counters)
- [Differences between Handle vs ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4120894/11465149)
- [ETW Listener Approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24080048/11465149)
- [Thread-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833256/how-to-check-how-many-bytes-my-application-wrote-and-read-from-disk)
- [helpful?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/929093ac-a20b-4e6e-aab0-1d484242ba10/getting-the-processortime-for-a-process?forum=netfxbcl)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetProcessDiskUsage` API to get the process IO information like number of Write and Read operations and total number of bytes read or written. The following code shows the process disk usage in **MB/s** like in Task Manager.

[image]

```
    struct IO_COUNTERS
    {
        public ulong ReadOperationCount;
        public ulong WriteOperationCount;
        public ulong OtherOperationCount;
        public ulong ReadTransferCount;
        public ulong WriteTransferCount;
        public ulong OtherTransferCount;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool GetProcessIoCounters(IntPtr ProcessHandle, out IO_COUNTERS IoCounters);

    private static double GetProcessDiskUsage(IntPtr processHandle)
    {

        IO_COUNTERS ioC1 = new IO_COUNTERS();
        GetProcessIoCounters(processHandle, out ioC1);
        double totalBytes1 = (ioC1.ReadTransferCount + ioC1.WriteTransferCount) / 1024f / 1024f;

        int time = 1;
        Thread.Sleep(time * 1000);

        IO_COUNTERS ioC2 = new IO_COUNTERS();
        GetProcessIoCounters(processHandle, out ioC2);
        double totalBytes2 = (ioC2.ReadTransferCount + ioC2.WriteTransferCount) / 1024f / 1024f;

        return (totalBytes2 - totalBytes1) / time;

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the process ID:");

        if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int processId))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid process ID");
            return;
        }

        Process process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);

        while (true)
        {
            double disk = Math.Round(GetProcessDiskUsage(process.Handle), 2);

            Console.WriteLine($"{process.ProcessName}: {disk} MB/s");

        }

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [DriveInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Info {
    public static void Main() {
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives) {
            //There are more attributes you can use.
            //Check the MSDN link for a complete example.
            Console.WriteLine(drive.Name);
            if (drive.IsReady) Console.WriteLine(drive.TotalSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives information about the full drive, not its usage by a single process

Comment: Ah right, my apologies. I found this previous post that has a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021903/how-to-get-per-process-disk-activity-in-windows

Comment: This worked for free disk space